# DataTable, multiple search terms, multiple columns

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have several search terms that I have to match with several fields of a database (an existing Access database), returning any record that matches all the terms, regardless which field matches which term.

Let's assume the search terms are: 'John, Boston' and 'London' and the target fields are 'name, surname' and 'city'.

I have to find both: a man named 'John Boston from London' and a man named 'John London from Boston'

As far I've tried:

```
        string initialQuery = "SELECT * FROM clientTable WHERE name like '%firstTerm%' or surname like '%firstTerm%' or city like '%firstTerm%'";
        var queryDs = new DataSet();
        OleDbDataAdapter clientesDa;
        OleDbConnection con = CreateOleDbConnection();
        clientesDa = new OleDbDataAdapter(initialQuery, con);
        clientesDa.Fill(queryDs, tableName);
        DataTable resultDataTable = queryDs.Tables["clientTable"];
        DataRow[] clientes = resultDataTable.Select("name like '%secondTerm%' or surname like '%secondTerm%' or city like '%secondTerm%'");
```

I don't know how to further filter the resulting `Datarow[]` and also I guess there must be a better way to do this.

Can it be done only with SQL?

Can it be done with successive LINQ filters?

How would it be done in C#?

Comment: Yes, it can. Did you try writing any code yourself?

Comment: Yes, I get a Datatable from a SQL query (looking for the first term in all columns) then I did: resultDataTable.Select("name like '%secondTerm%' or surname like '%secondTerm%' or city like '%secondTerm%'"). That gives me a DataRow[] an then 1. I don't know how to further filter and 2. I'm shure there is a better way to do it

Comment: Have you tried searching for FullTextSearch in Sql Server(assuming you are using SQL Server 200X)

Comment: @Ranjan Thanks for the advice but it's an Access Database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding as another answer, due to comment size limitations:

I've got to attend to another issue right now, but the easiest answer to your question is this: Let the database work for you.  It's what they're designed for.  You are over-complicating the issue by going beyond ONE `initialQuery` -- your *entire* query can be solved by *using C# to build a single appropriate query string*:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT blah blah blah   -- what data you want?
FROM some_tables                 -- where do you want it from?
WHERE important stuff here       -- THIS IS YOUR QUESTION!!!
```

IOW, what you are probably best off doing here is building *a single SQL query with a compound WHERE clause that reflects the parameters limiting the result set to what you actually want*.

Remember:

SQL is a SET-ORIENTED language.
C#/C++/Java/most others you'll deal with professionally are DECLARITIVE/OO languages.

This is an important distinction.  They are not only oriented toward different problems, they exist in completely different problem *domains*.

Your problem *in SQL* is simple.  One query, with appropriate `WHERE` clauses and conditions.  That's it.

In a language such as C#, however, it becomes a more difficult problem -- we have to actually *create* those "appropriate" WHERE clauses and conditions.  All of which leads us back to the first point, slightly re-phrased: let the *language* work for you.  Searching databases in SQL, *given appropriate query strings* is great.  Actually *building* those query strings in SQL sucks.  Not so in C#, and vice-versa.

So, *use the strengths of the language you are doing most of your work in*.  In your case, it seems we're talking C#.

So: what do you want your SQL query to look like?  Build it using C#, then just execute it to obtain the desired result set.

*One* query, appropriately constructed.  C# to build it, then use the DB engine to actually execute it (note: doesn't matter if it's Access, MS-SQL, whatever - let ODBC take the hit on this one).

As a starting point given your example, consider what you might want to do to generate (using C#) the following string (mostly pseudo-code, again off the top of my head):

```sql
SELECT               -- well, you want some data, right?
DISTINCT             -- you don´t want to dup *every* record matching the WHERE clause
*                    -- your code assumes you want *all* fields for a matching record
FROM clientTable     -- you only specified one table to search
WHERE                -- now HERE´s the part that matters:
(
  name LIKE %firstTerm%   
  OR name LIKE %secondTerm%
  OR name LIKE %thirdTerm%
)
OR
(
  surname LIKE %firstTerm% 
  OR surname LIKE %secondTerm%
  OR surname LIKE %thirdTerm%
)
OR
(
  city LIKE %firstTerm% 
  OR city LIKE %secondTerm%
  OR city LIKE %thirdTerm%
)
```

There are several other (better/cleaner/expert) ways to do this, but that is generally the most basic aspect: what query string do you need to create to meet your requirements?  As a bonus, this approach (keeping the database work in the database realm) will generally be much faster than creating subsets of data, querying them into a further subset, etc.  One query (whenever this is possible), with multiple WHERE clauses could be orders of magnitude faster than creating and repeatedly/recursively querying temporary datasets.

Caveat: none of the off-the-cuff code may work as-is.  For illustration purposes only. Posted on my way out of the door.

Comment: frasnian, thanks a lot for your answer. Correct me if I'm wrong but the SQL Query you posted will get all records that match any term in any field (even if only one term matches). As I need all the terms to match at least one field, I guess two changes are needed: 1- inside the parenthesis I need to look 1 word against the 3 fields (not the opposite), so I have one TRUE/FALSE for each word and not for each field. Also each ") OR (" between parenthesis shoud be an ") AND (" to require the 3 words matches to be TRUE. Am I Right? Thanks again!

Comment: @SantiagoVaz: I believe you're correct. I was hurrying when I posted, so I really wouldn't trust my SQL from this morning anyway :)